# How can I connect with my friend over the web using winsocket2?

Tags: c, winapi

This question is similar to others but I found so much information I am not sure what is important and what not anymore.

What I am doing is a simple chat program where I create the server and my friend and I both  have one socket to send messages through.

Server side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

SOCKET start_server(void)
{
    INT iResult;
    SOCKET sock;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("192.168.70.3", "666", &hints, &result);
    if(iResult)
    {
        printf("> error: getaddrinfo failed (error code: %d)\n", iResult);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    sock = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("> error: socket failed (error code: %d)\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(sock, result->ai_addr, (int) result->ai_addrlen);
    if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("> error: bind failed (error code: %d)\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(sock);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return sock;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[1024];
    SOCKET serverSock;
    SOCKET socks[2];
    WSADATA wsaData;
    INT iRetval;
    if((iRetval = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData)))
    {
        printf("> error: Startup failed(error code: 0xF0%x)\n", iRetval);
        return 0xFF;
    }
    printf("> Connecting to server...\n");
    serverSock = start_server();
    printf("> Connected to server...\n");
    printf("> Listening for connections..\n");
    listen(serverSock, 0);
    socks[0] = accept(serverSock, NULL, NULL);
    printf("> One client connected\n");
    listen(serverSock, 0);
    socks[1] = accept(serverSock, NULL, NULL);
    printf("> Another client connected\n");
    while(1)
    {
        if(recv(socks[0], buf, sizeof(buf), 0) > 0)
        {
            send(socks[1], buf, strlen(buf) + 1, 0);
        }
        if(recv(socks[1], buf, sizeof(buf), 0) > 0)
        {
            send(socks[0], buf, strlen(buf) + 1, 0);
        }
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client side:

```
SOCKET user_connect(void)
{
    SOCKET sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
    int iResult;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("public_ip_address", "666", &hints, &result);
    if(iResult)
    {
        printf("> error: getaddrinfo failed (error code: %d)\n", iResult);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr = result; ptr; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
    {
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        sock = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("> error: socket failed (error code: %d)\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        printf("> Trying to connect to: cannon name[%s], family[%d], protocol[%d], socket type[%d], flags[%d]\n", ptr->ai_canonname, ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_protocol, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_flags);
        iResult = connect(sock, ptr->ai_addr, (int) ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(sock);
            sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return sock;
}
```

The problem is that it fails establishing a connection. Note that it works when I use a local ip address instead of `public_ip_address` and open each component on my PC only.

So I got my public IP, local IP, even set up a Port Forwarding but I am not sure what gives.

My question is what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to establish a connection.

Comment: Are you both on the same [Local Area Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network)? Or are you communicating over internet? Note that many [ISPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) do not provide every customer with their own [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address, so that several customers must share one such IP address. In that case, you cannot accept incoming connection requests, i.e. you cannot act as a server, unless you use IPv6 instead.

Comment: Another possible issue is that [Windows Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Firewall]) (or any other firewall software that you may be using) may be interfering with incoming or outgoing connections, depending on how it is configured.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel We are not using LAN. The Firewall is not in the way. But I don't know how to check if my IPv4 address is unique.

Comment: @Lost Aside from the networking issue at the ISP level (which is the most likely cause of your problem in this case), there are several bugs in the code shown, too. Not using `listen()` correctly. Ignoring the return value of `recv()` when calling `send()`, not multiplexing the accepted connections, using `AF_INET` on the server but `AF_UNSPEC` on the client.

Comment: @Lost "*I don't know how to check if my IPv4 address is unique*" - unless you know other customers of the same ISP who are physically close to you and you all check with a site like whatismyip.com if you all have the same IP, there is really no way to determine that on your own. Just contact the ISP and ask instead.

Comment: Even if you both have a public IP address, it will almost certainly be assigned to your routers and not your actual PCs - they'll have a local IP address assigned by the router. Additionally, most home routers usually block incoming connections by default. You'll need to open up ports in your routers and redirect them to the appropriate computer on the local network.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: OP stated in the question that they set up "a Port Forwarding", so we can probably assume that OP handled that issue.